# Is there a way to delete zip archive comments in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, zip

I have multiple zip archives all with a similar comment.

Is there a way to delete the comment from the archives with python and use it over multiple archives with similar comment?

**What I have tried with single archive**

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('D:\XXX\Desktop\MyZip.zip', 'r')
del archive.comment
```

This is not working. Comment is not getting deleted in the archive, plus I want this to work on multiple archives in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the zipfile in read mode with 'r' parameter. Use a mode that enables you to modify the file. Then set comment  to '' instead of deleting it.